# magento custom payment method redirect

Tags: php, magento, redirect, paypal, payment-gateway

I am trying to build custom payment method. It should work as paypal, when user cliks on "Place order" it should redirect him on external gatewey. The trick is that it has to send POST data.

To create module I folowed severeal tutorials, but mostly this one [Incho](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/)

Model/Standard.php

```
   public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
   {
    Mage::Log('Called ' . __METHOD__);
    return Mage::getUrl('payment/Standard/Redirect', array('_secure' => true));
   }
```

After i click on procedure it redirects me on

```
> http://192.168.0.15/magento/index.php/payment/Standard/Redirect
```

and I get 404 error. In log file i can see that it hitted method getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl, bu it didn't come to redirectAction. Can anybody help me with this issue, I am newbie to magento.

controllers/StandardController.php

```
 public function redirectAction()
{       
 Mage::Log('Called ' . __METHOD__);
//do something
}
```

Block/Standard/Redirect.php

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
Mage::Log('Called ' . __METHOD__);
    //do POST
}
```

Comment: Did you create the required controller for the url? In your tutorial it reads "If your method redirect when customer click on checkout button place order you have to create (customcard/standard/redirect) standard controller with method redirectAction and etc."

Comment: Hi! I created StandardController.php inside Controller folder

Comment: Please show how you registered in config.xml. Make sure you cleared the cache after adding it.

Comment: I didn't register controller explicitly. I watched at paypal config and I didnt found anything similar. Should I register controller and how?

Comment: I didn't create phtml for block, is that maybe a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phtml file should not be the probleme here. In the tutorial the controller is registered like this:

```
   <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mycheckout>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Inchoo_Mycheckout</module>
                    <frontname>customcard</frontname>
                </args>
            </mycheckout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

Also make `'customcard/standard/redirect'` lowercase. If you need further support and changed module and classnames, add them to your question.

Comment: It wasnt exactly this but it was something regarding namespaces. To all you who have same problem pay big attention to namespaces, especialiy to lower or upper case charahetrs.